# Flutter OneSignal External User Id

Tags: flutter, dart, onesignal

In Flutter is there any way to push notification for user based apps.
In documentation i have to use `external_user_id` for this. But in Flutter i cant find this function.

```
await OneSignal.shared.postNotificationWithJson({
   
    "include_external_user_ids": ["123456789"],
    "contents": {"en": "test notification"}
  });
```

then i tried with postNotificationWithJson but it returns this error

```
 PlatformException (PlatformException(OneSignal, Encountered an error attempting to postNotification {"errors":["Please include a case-sensitive header of Authorization: Basic <YOUR-REST-API-KEY-HERE> or Bearer token=\"<YOUR-REST-API-KEY-HERE>\" with a valid REST API key."],"reference":["https:\/\/documentation.onesignal.com\/docs\/accounts-and-keys#section-keys-ids"]}, {reference: [https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/accounts-and-keys#section-keys-ids], errors: [Please include a case-sensitive header of Authorization: Basic <YOUR-REST-API-KEY-HERE> or Bearer token="<YOUR-REST-API-KEY-HERE>" with a valid REST API key.]}, null))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Flutter `one_signal ^3.5.1` i didn't find something for this.

```
void sendNotification(String externalUserId, String message) async {
  try {
    var url = Uri.parse("https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
    var client = http.Client();

    var headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      "Authorization": "Basic $key", //from one signal
    };

    var body = {
      "app_id": appId,
      "contents": {"en": message},
      "include_external_user_ids": [externalUserId],
    };

    var response =
        await client.post(url, headers: headers, body: json.encode(body));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print("Notification sent successfully");
    } else {
      print("Error sending notification: ${response.statusCode}");
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    }
```

You can use post with html with this method